# Looking for Zigbee and Microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, wireless, zigbee

Looking for Zigbee and Microcontroller - **Selection**

[image]

- What series Zigbee wireless should I get?
- SAM R21 Xplained Pro for MUC to connect some sensor and zigbee.
- Wireless adapter should be something special?

This's my first project so I have a lot to learn. Thank you all.

Comment: First project? In electronics? Or with a Zigbee? As it stands this is a "shopping" question, with no research done, and will be closed. Googling "[zigbee wireless](https://www.google.com/?ion=1&espv=2#q=zigbee%20wireless)" returned 424,000 hits. If you edit the question to be more specific, it may be salvageable.

Answer (score 2):

You do have a lot to learn - we all always do the same, no worries on that :)

This is a project which can make the eyebrows of senior engineers to lift. 1-2km with Zigbee is very very hard to reach, even in full line of sight - at least I have very bad experiences even with the dedicated long range Zigbee modules.

In order to reach that, you shall do a little research on antenna theory, and use directional antennas - which rules out the PC plug in wireless adapter alltogether.

Moreover, it seems that you made a few premature decisions (for example, picking Zigbee without considering other, better solutions, picking the microcontroller first without considering the easiest and best match for this goal). You may have perfect reasonings for picking these - but please clearly specify, *why*.

For example, I could do this project as:

- buy a 4$ ESP8266 module with external antenna
- get or make a cantenna - directional access, 1-2 km is doable
- apply a cantenna to the esp and to a simple off-the-shelf wifi router, so you have a wifi link
- pick a 10$ Arduino and refer to the endless esp8266 tutorials on the web.

If you are not a beginner, I would also suggest using a LoRa ISM radio module, which allows you to easily pass this distance without too much antenna magic, and you could pick a standalone microcontroller and use its power savings mode. With 2 AA batteries, the whole sensor node works for many months using ESP8266 and standard Wifi.